# use numerical pad for shortcuts

Tags: gnome

first of all sorry for my English.

In firefox it is possible to use the numerical pad for shortcuts with numbers, for example Alt+1 to move to the first tab. But when I switch to another program like the terminal it doesn't work. Is there a possibility to enable that generally?

Regards
Johannes

Comment: Sorry that I forgot  this.

Scientifc Linux, running with gnome

Comment: Hi Johannes, this is not the best place to ask your question. I've flagged it as "not related to programming", since it looks a lot more like a user interface question related to a particular distribution. Hope you do come back with more relevant questions though :)

Answer (score 0):

The `alt+<number>` shortcut is Firefox specific. The tabs are handled by Firefox itself.

In Gnome terminal you also have options to navigate between tabs, for example `Ctrl+PgUp/PgDn` to move to next or previous tab.

Comment: My question wasn't precise enough.
I found out that I can use Alt+1 in the terminal to move to the first tab. But I have to use the numbers on the top of the keyboard. It doesn't work when I use the "1" from the numerical pad. In Contrast to this in firefox I can alos use the "1" from the numerical pad.